# Odd alias "find . -name '*\!{*}*' -ls" in Unix Power Tools

Tags: find, wildcards, alias, csh

From Unix Power Tools 3rd Edition page 175:

> Article 9.27 shows a way to match directories in the middle of a path.  Here's a simpler "find file" alias that can come in very handy:
>
> `alias ff "find . -name '*\!{*}*' -ls"`
>
> Give it a file or directory name; the alias will give a long listing of any file or directory names that contain the argument.

(This is also [available online](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_04.htm).)

I don't get the argument to the `-name` operator at all.  Is this a typo?  Is it only for specific versions of `find`?  What are the backslash, bang and curly braces doing?

Comment: Which shell are they using? That doesn't look like bash. Otherwise I'd have guessed `!{*}` to be some sort of history interaction.

Comment: Most of the book (the parts that I've read so far) are either not shell specific or are very good about specifying what is non-portable or `zsh` specific, etc.  This one article/section appears to be an oddity.  It's definitely not `bash`; they don't even have an `=` sign to set the alias.  The rest of the book seems quite excellent but this one line is "WTF?!"

Comment: It looks like (t)csh (`!` is alias argument expansion).

Comment: would you accept *or what*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a `csh` alias; the argument given to `-name` is interpreted by the shell, not by `find`. If I understand it correctly, `\!{*}` is replaced by the arguments given to `ff` (although that would usually just be `\!*`). It is odd indeed that the book doesn't specify the shell...

Basically with the alias defined, typing

```
ff test
```

runs

```
find . -name '*test*' -ls
```

(and it doesn't handle multiple arguments gracefully).

In the second edition of the book, the text defines the alias in the same way as given in the question, and points to `csh_init` and `sh_init` on the accompanying CD. (It's section 17.04.) Intriguingly, `csh_init` on the CD doesn't define the alias, but `sh_init` defines an equivalent `ff` function:

```
ff() { find . -name "*$1*" -ls; }
```

Comment: That's it exactly, and now it makes sense.  As you say it is odd indeed that they didn't specify the shell for that one.  I'll have to stay on the lookout.  But in fairness to the authors, I'd say the need for a little watchfulness is still worth it; the book is *excellent* and should be a staple for sysadmins.

Comment: The book is indeed excellent, I have the second edition and learnt a lot from it back in the day!